# How can I get object values from authorize .net payment getway response

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

authorize.net sample code gives the response in below two method.

```
echo "Charge Credit Card AUTH CODE : " . $tresponse->getAuthCode() . "\n";
echo "Charge Credit Card TRANS ID  : " . $tresponse->getTransId() . "\n";
```

I want all methods with class name to print complete response

Answer (score 0):

You might have figured it out by now. But I'm posting my solution for all others who see this question.
I created an array in order to break down the $tresponse object.

```
if ($response != null){
$tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
$result = array(
    'response' => ($response != null)? true: false,
    'getResultCode' => $response->getMessages()->getResultCode(),
    'getMessages' => ($response->getTransactionResponse()->getMessages() != null)? array(
        'msjCode' => $response->getTransactionResponse()->getMessages()[0]->getCode(),
        'msjDesc' => $response->getTransactionResponse()->getMessages()[0]->getDescription()
    ): null,
    'getResponseCode' => ($tresponse->getResponseCode() != null)? $tresponse->getResponseCode(): null,
    'getAuthCode' => ($tresponse->getAuthCode() != null)? $tresponse->getAuthCode(): null,
    'getTransId' => ($tresponse->getTransId() != null)? $tresponse->getTransId(): null,
    'messageCode' => ($tresponse->getMessages() != null)? $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getCode(): null,
    'msgDescription' => ($tresponse->getMessages() != null)? $tresponse->getMessages()[0]->getDescription(): null,
    'transactionResponseErrors' => ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)? array(
        'errorText' => $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText(),
        'errorCode' => $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode()
    ): null,
    'getErrorCode' => ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)?  $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode(): null,
    'getErrorText' => ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)? $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText(): null,
    'userCardNumber' => $userCardNumber,
    'userCardExpMonth' => $userCardExpMonth,
    'userCardExpYear' => $userCardExpYear
    );
}else{
    $tresponse = $response->getTransactionResponse();
    $result = array(
    'response' => ($response != null)? true: false,
    'transactionResponseErrors' => ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)? array(
        'errorText' => $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText(),
        'errorCode' => $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode()
    ): null,
    'getErrorCode' => ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)?  $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorCode(): null,
    'getErrorText' => ($tresponse->getErrors() != null)? $tresponse->getErrors()[0]->getErrorText(): null,
    'messageCode' => ($response->getMessages()->getMessage() != null)? $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getCode(): null,
    'messageText' => ($response->getMessages()->getMessage() != null)? $response->getMessages()->getMessage()[0]->getText(): null
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

The resulting json object looks like this:

```
{
"response": true,
"getResultCode": "Error",
"getMessages": null,
"getResponseCode": "3",
"getAuthCode": null,
"getTransId": "0",
"messageCode": null,
"msgDescription": null,
"transactionResponseErrors": {
"errorText": "The credit card number is invalid.",
"errorCode": "6"
},
"getErrorCode": "6",
"getErrorText": "The credit card number is invalid.",
"userCardNumber": "\t44444",
"userCardExpMonth": "12",
"userCardExpYear": "2018"
}
```